# "( foo && bar && baz ); finally-code" <- how can finally-code not be run?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I have this node.js code which generates a bash script:

```
const k = cp.spawn('bash');

let cmd = [
  `cd ${v.path}`,
  `git checkout "${releaseName}"`,
  `git add .`,
  `git commit -am "modified package.json"`,
  `git checkout master`,
  `( git branch -D -f master_copy_npp_tool &> /dev/null || echo "" ) `,
  `git checkout -b master_copy_npp_tool`,
  `git merge --no-commit -m "This release branch should be merged into master and integration." "${releaseName}"`,
  `git checkout ${releaseName}`,
  `git push -u origin ${releaseName}`
]
.join(' && ');

cmd = `( ${cmd} ); git checkout -f master; `;  // always checkout the integration branch again, at the end

k.stdin.end(cmd);
```

For some reason, the script leaves the git repo on the `releaseName` branch, not `master`.

The command as a string looks like:

```
( cd /home/rolo/foo
&& git checkout "oleg/npp_tool/release/1531621240127"
&& git add . && git commit -am "modified package.json"
&& git checkout master
&& ( git branch -D -f master_copy_npp_tool &> /dev/null || echo "" )
&& git checkout -b master_copy_npp_tool
&& git merge --no-commit -m "(shortened)." "oleg/npp_tool/release/1531621240127"
&& git checkout oleg/npp_tool/release/1531621240127
&& git push -u origin oleg/npp_tool/release/1531621240127 );
git checkout -f master;
```

I am trying to use the last clause:

```
git checkout -f master;
```

as a "finally" block. I want to always checkout the master branch in the end no matter way. Anyone know what's going wrong? Like I said it remains on the release branch.

Basically what I tried to do is this pattern:

```
( foo && bar && star ); finally-clause;
```

Comment: The pattern itself is sound -- but any parser failure will abort, whether the subshell succeeded or not; and since you aren't using `eval`-safe escaping for substituted strings, we can't be certain that their contents won't result in a parse-time failure.

Comment: You'd be on far more solid ground if you invoked a constant script that referred to positional arguments for its parameters; then the only content being parsed is... well... constant; also resolves potential for attempts at shell injection attacks.

Comment: ...the generated code you included in the question parses, but it has the `(shortened).` string. If your *real* string there included literal quotes, f/e, things are suddenly interesting.

Comment: Anyhow, if you want to try to debug what's going on, capture stderr -- optionally passing `bash -x` to the interpreter at its startup. But again, I strongly recommend separating data from code; invoking `["bash", "-c", CONSTANT_SCRIPT, "_", releaseName, v.path, ...]` (and using `"$1"` in `CONSTANT_SCRIPT` to refer to `releaseName`, `"$2"` to refer to `v.path`, etc) puts you on the road to a much more robust solution.

Comment: thanks @CharlesDuffy that makes sense let me give it a go

Comment: I think what was happening is that I was running `cd` inside the subshell, and outside the subshell calling git again, but it was in the wrong dir, that's the problem. IOW, `git checkout -f master` was happening in the wrong repo lol, because the `cd` command was only in the subshell. I don't think it's worth keep the question up, will prob delete it.

Comment: So the finally code *was* running, it was just running in the wrong repo (and therefore not failing)